# Pointer issue on linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

As most beginners in C, I'm implementing a simple linked list.

Each node for the list is defined as so:

```
typedef struct list_node {
    void * data;
    struct list_node * next;
} list_node_t;
```

I made a test program to create and iterate a list. Creation and insertion operations work correctly. However, the code below is giving me problems:

```
list_node_t * node = NULL;

list_iter_reset(list, node);

if (node == NULL) {
    printf("Node is NULL.\n");
} else {
    printf("Node is not NULL.\n");
}
fflush(stdout);
```

The function `list_iter_reset()` is defined below. Please note that `list->head` does not point to NULL, as I have inserted nodes in the list previously.

```
void list_iter_reset(list_t list, list_node_t * node)
{
    node = list->head;

    if (node == NULL) {
        printf("Node is NULL.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Node is not NULL.\n");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

The output from executing that code is as follows:

```
Node is not NULL.
Node is NULL.
```

Since I'm passing a pointer to the node to the function, why is the created node in the test program still pointing to NULL after that function call?

I'm guessing a simple pointer arithmetic aspect went over my head here. I've been looking around and could not find a similar issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems you want to be passing a pointer to pointer (`list_node_t**`) to the function, not a pointer. The function is modifying the value of the pointer (`node`), but that never gets back to the caller.

Comment: I think you need to pass the node pointer as a reference `list_node* &node`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This might sound ingenuous, but shouldn't the pointer to the node be all I need to change its value? Since I'm passing the memory address of the node to the function, why would I need the "second level" of memory access?

Comment: @GregK This is `c`. There are no references.

Comment: @Rotem Oh yeah you are absolutely right, I forgot. Then double pointer it is :)

Comment: @SaucyGoat Great question! A pointer is all you need to change the value of *the thing it's pointing to*. But here, you are trying to change the value of *the pointer itself*. It takes a while to wrap your head around it but seems like you're on the right track. As a comparison, imagine you would be passing an `int` to the function an expecting the function to change that `int`. You would of course have to pass an `int*`, right? This is the same thing, except replace `int` with `node*`, and so you need to pass a `node**`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you kindly leave an answer so I can mark this question as solved? I'm guessing this could be quite helpful to other C noobies around :)

Comment: @SaucyGoat done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is modifying the value of the pointer, but that never gets back to the caller. It seems you want to be passing a *[pointer to pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_pointer.htm)* (`list_node_t**`) to the function, not a regular pointer.

```
void list_iter_reset(list_t list, list_node_t** node)
{
    *node = list->head;

    ...
}
```

The reasoning for this is that while a pointer is all you need to change *the value of the thing it's pointing to*, here you are trying to change the value of *the pointer itself*, i.e. where this pointer is pointing to.

As a comparison, imagine you would be passing an `int` to the function and expecting the function to modify that `int`. You would of course have to pass an `int*`, right? This is the same thing, except replace `int` with `node*`, and so you need to pass a pointer to that type, which in this case is `node**`

Comment: The `if` should also be changed to use `*node`.